# Why Unable to Install WFDB?

Tags: matlab

I am installing WFDB Toolbox for Matlab 2016a in Ubuntu Linux 14.04 64bit, which instructions are [here](https://physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/). 
I do

```
[old_path]=which('rdsamp');if(~isempty(old_path)) rmpath(old_path(1:end-8)); end
wfdb_url='http://physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9.zip';
[filestr,status] = urlwrite(wfdb_url,'wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9.zip');%Octave users may have to download manually
unzip('wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9.zip');
cd wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9;cd mcode
addpath(pwd);savepath
```

I get a permission issue

```
Warning: Unable to save path to file '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/toolbox/local/pathdef.m'. You
can save your path to a different location by calling SAVEPATH with an input argument that
specifies the full path. For MATLAB to use that path in future sessions, save the path to
'pathdef.m' in your MATLAB startup folder.
```

I would like to save to the default location indicated in the error i.e. by per-user pathdef.m file.

### Results of thrig's answer

- Works in the latest update of Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
- Does not work in OS X El Capitan.

Do in Terminal

```
echo "export MATLAB_USE_USERWORK=1" >> $HOME/.bashrc
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r \ 
    "userpath('/home/masi/Documents/bin/matlab/'); exit;"
```

Final setup

```
if (exist('old_path', 'var') == 0) 
    home='/home/masi/';
    [old_path]=which('rdsamp');if(~isempty(old_path)) rmpath(old_path(1:end-8)); end
    wfdb_url='http://physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9.zip';
    [filestr,status] = urlwrite(wfdb_url,'wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9.zip');%Octave users may have to download manually
    unzip('wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9.zip');
    cd(fullfile(home, 'wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9', 'mcode'));
    addpath(fullfile(home, 'wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9/mcode/')); % me
    %addpath(fullfile('wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-9', 'mcode'));
    % Bug command sets userpath to '', why? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38283814/54964
    %savepath(fullfile(home, 'pathdef.m')); % ~/pathdef.m originally
end
```

---

How can you install WFDB by per-user pathdef.m file in Matlab 2016a?

Comment: Isn't it a simple permissions issue? If you really are determined to save it there (rather than the recommended way of using a per-user pathdef.m file) then probably the least disruptive way is to temporarily give the file write permission for 'other'. Don't forget to change it back when you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (temporarily) assign write permission to that file for the user, e.g. `sudo chown youruseraccount /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/toolbox/local/pathdef.m` and then do the install, and change the permissions back. But this won't fly if you lack privileges to do so. Another option is to change the `savepath` call to write a custom `pathdef.m`:

```
$ cd
$ matlab
...
>> mkdir wfdb
>> cd wfdb
>> [old_path]=which('rdsamp');if(~isempty(old_path)) rmpath(old_path(1:end-8)); end
...
>> savepath ~/pathdef.m
>> exit
...
$ matlab
...
>> wfdb
```

This assumes that your home directory is your startup folder for matlab, though the `pathdef.m` could be saved to some other directory and matlab started up from that directory, or the initial folder path changed in the matlab preferences.